# WolframAlpha norm notation

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I am having problems to understand the notation of a WolframAlpha result. Evaluating [this equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdu%20(norm(x-u,%202)%5E2-z)%5E2), I am getting following:

$$-4 \ ||-u + x||_2 \ (-z + ||-u + x||_2^2) \ \text{Norm}^{(1,0)}(-u + x, 2)$$

How can I interpret the following notation: $\text{Norm}^{(1,0)}(-u + x, 2)$? I do not get the $(1,0)$ part in the exponential.